# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to run a python file, but I get  this error:

```
  File "/home/hadi/Software/tensorflow/TEST_FRCN_ROOT/tools/../lib/datasets/pascal_voc.py", line 212, in _load_pascal_annotation
    cls = self._class_to_ind[obj.find('name').text.lower().strip()]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

This is the part of the code which makes the error:

```
%%  Load object bounding boxes into a data frame.
        for ix, obj in enumerate(objs):
            bbox = obj.find('bndbox')
            # Make pixel indexes 0-based
            x1 = float(bbox.find('xmin').text) - 1
            y1 = float(bbox.find('ymin').text) - 1
            x2 = float(bbox.find('xmax').text) - 1
            y2 = float(bbox.find('ymax').text) - 1
            cls = self._class_to_ind[obj.find('name').text.lower().strip()]
            boxes[ix, :] = [x1, y1, x2, y2]
            gt_classes[ix] = cls
            overlaps[ix, cls] = 1.0
            seg_areas[ix] = (x2 - x1 + 1) * (y2 - y1 + 1)
```

Can I add a condition to deal with any **none** object here?

Comment: So what should happen instead, if there is no text in `obj.find('name')`? Sure you can add a condition, but what if that condition doesn't match?

Comment: So do I have to check every file to see if there is an object with missing name attribute? there are like 1200 files. Is there any other way?

Comment: That's not what I said, and you are not answering my question.

Comment: actually this shouldn't happen at all, because I'm sure all the objects have a name tag with a text inside.

Comment: Yet you have an error here proving that this isn't the case.

Comment: If something else happens in the condition, I would lose some objects. But I don't think it's that many to be so important. So anything can happen in the condition as long as it ignores the empty attribute.

Comment: That's not a very helpful response; I want you to pick something *specific*.

Comment: Can I add some code to show me which file is the missing name occurring?

Comment: I don't know, you haven't shown enough information about the `obj` type to see if we can trace back their origin to a file.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks a lot. the pass option below made the error go away for now. But based on your comment I should check each file to find the corrupted ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use like this

```
for ix, obj in enumerate(objs):
            bbox = obj.find('bndbox')
            # Make pixel indexes 0-based
            x1 = float(bbox.find('xmin').text) - 1
            y1 = float(bbox.find('ymin').text) - 1
            x2 = float(bbox.find('xmax').text) - 1
            y2 = float(bbox.find('ymax').text) - 1
            if obj.find('name').text != None:
              cls = self._class_to_ind[obj.find('name').text.lower().strip()]
              boxes[ix, :] = [x1, y1, x2, y2]
              gt_classes[ix] = cls
              overlaps[ix, cls] = 1.0
              seg_areas[ix] = (x2 - x1 + 1) * (y2 - y1 + 1)
```

Comment: Use `if cls is None:`, no need to use the slow option.

Comment: And it is the `.text` attribute that is `None`, not the return value of `find()`, according to the traceback.

Comment: `.text` is `None`, updated the code

Comment: What should I put instead of `cls`in front of if?

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad use the updated code, and try to see if it works or not

Comment: @SoumeshBanerjee thanks for the code. It worked, but there is an **assertion error** in another file now which I don't think is relevant to this question.